# Checking the first digit in a number in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that reads in a vars_file containing usernames and uids

```
users:
  - name: josh
    uid: 1201
  - name: peter
    uid: 1202
  - name: paul
    uid: 2101
  - name: ryan
    uid: 2102
```

I have two host groups in my inventory file, db and web. I want users to be created in db if their uid starts with a 1, and web if it starts with 2.

My playbook so far looks like this

```
---
- name: users playbook
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  vars_files:
    - vars/user_list.yml

  tasks:

  - name: test debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.username }}, {{ item.uid }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
    when: '{{ item.uid[0] }} == 1'
```

But my when conditional throws the error 
    The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ item.uid[0] }} == 1)

Is there a better way of doing this for both conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems.

First, you are not comparing anything. In the expression `'{{ item.uid[0] }} == 1'` the last part (i.e. `== 1`) will be literally treated as a string and written as output. If used in a full jinja2 expression, the comparison must be inside the markers: `{{ item.uid[0] == 1 }}`

Second, `when` clauses should not contain any jinja2 markers to expand variables. This is also the case for `failed_when` and `changed_when`. See the [conditionals doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

Lastly, getting the character with an index will only work if the input is a string and not an int. So you first need to make sure or that by casting it correctly with the [`string` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#string). The char you will then get will be itself a string. Comparing it to an integer will always return `false`. So you either have to write the comparison value as a string (i.e. `'1'`) or cast the extracted car to an integer with the [`int` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#int).

This is how I would fix your task:

```
  - name: test debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.username }}, {{ item.uid }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
    when: (item.uid | string)[0] | int == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. doing that throws the error:  The conditional check 'item.uid[0] | int == 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.uid[0] | int == 1): int object has no element 0

Comment: Well then it was not casted to string. I'm updating my response.

Comment: That was it, much appreciated.